# Attempted to load class "WebProfilerBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle" when deploying on Heroku using development dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, symfony4, heroku-ci

We have a Symfony 4.3 web application hosted on Heroku. This is a new setup and **we never managed to have the dev mode to work correctly**. There are plenty of similar issues online but none fixes the exact symptoms we are facing here.

The project was created with a command line:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton appName
```

Let me clarify that: **we do not want to** change **from** "dev" **to** "prod"

We need to be able to use the application in dev mode in order to take advantage of error debugging for PHP as per the [article "How to Customize Error Pages" for Symfony 4.3 here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html)

```
$ php bin/console about
 -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
  Symfony
 -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
  Version              4.3.5
  End of maintenance   01/2020
  End of life          07/2020
 -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
  Kernel
 -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
  Type                 App\Kernel
  Environment          dev
  Debug                true
  Charset              UTF-8
  Cache directory      ./var/cache/dev (12.1 MiB)
  Log directory        ./var/log (13 KiB)
 -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
  PHP
 -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
  Version              7.3.10
  Architecture         64 bits
  Intl locale          n/a
  Timezone             Europe/Berlin (2019-10-28T15:48:05+01:00)
  OPcache              false
  APCu                 false
  Xdebug               false
 -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
  Environment (.env)
 -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
  APP_ENV              dev
 *just a few removed before posting for privacy*
 -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
```

If we change from 'dev' to 'prod' environment the application works but we cannot see the errors the way we wish to. We could use the command below (but this is not the point we are trying to solve here) in order to use "Symfony Var Dumper Server". We do not want to use this method.

```
./bin/console server:dump
```

It seems that we might be missing a dependency but `composer update` and `composer install` and `composer dump-autoload` did not solve anything.

Also note the message "**Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /tmp/build_a45354eb0ee7b20dd7ec870ed4fb1980/src/Kernel.php:23**" - Is it possible that the WebProfilerBundle is broken in the master repository?

To further help understand the situation, below is the `composer.json` file

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.1",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
        "symfony/asset": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/intl": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/process": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/validator": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.14",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/test-pack": "*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.3.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Our obstacle: trying to deploy to heroku using `dev` mode.

```
git push heroku master
```

which fails with the following message:

```
remote:        Executing script cache:clear [KO]
remote:         [KO]
remote:        Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
remote:        !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "WebProfilerBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle".
remote:        !!  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /tmp/build_a45354eb0ee7b20dd7ec870ed4fb1980/src/Kernel.php:23
remote:        !!  Stack trace:
remote:        !!  #0 /tmp/build_a45354eb0ee7b20dd7ec870ed4fb1980/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(429): App\Kernel->registerBundles()
remote:        !!  #1 /tmp/build_a45354eb0ee7b20dd7ec870ed4fb1980/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(130): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
remote:        !!  #2 /tmp/build_a45354eb0ee7b20dd7ec870ed4fb1980/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(159): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
remote:        !!  #3 /tmp/build_a45354eb0ee7b20dd7ec870ed4fb1980/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(65): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands()
remote:        !!  #4 /tmp/build_a45354eb0ee7b20dd7ec870ed4fb1980/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Cons in /tmp/build_a45354eb0ee7b20dd7ec870ed4fb1980/src/Kernel.php
on line 23
remote:        !!
remote:        Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
remote:  !     WARNING: There was a class not found error in your code
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
remote:  !     - There was a class not found error in your code
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

We currently do not know how to install or verify that bundles are indeed present and operational for Symfony 4.3 - ideas in this direction might help but not only.

```
php bin/console config:dump-reference

Available registered bundles with their extension alias if available
====================================================================

 ---------------------------- ------------------------
  Bundle name                  Extension alias
 ---------------------------- ------------------------
  DebugBundle                  debug
  DoctrineBundle               doctrine
  DoctrineCacheBundle          doctrine_cache
  DoctrineMigrationsBundle     doctrine_migrations
  FrameworkBundle              framework
  MakerBundle                  maker
  MonologBundle                monolog
  SecurityBundle               security
  SensioFrameworkExtraBundle   sensio_framework_extra
  SwiftmailerBundle            swiftmailer
  TwigBundle                   twig
  TwigExtraBundle              twig_extra
  WebProfilerBundle            web_profiler
  WebServerBundle              web_server
  WebpackEncoreBundle          webpack_encore
 ---------------------------- ------------------------

 // Provide the name of a bundle as the first argument of this command to dump its default configuration. (e.g.
 // config:dump-reference FrameworkBundle)
 //
 // For dumping a specific option, add its path as the second argument of this command. (e.g.
 // config:dump-reference FrameworkBundle profiler.matcher to dump the
 // framework.profiler.matcher configuration)
```

Comment: I am open to the speculation that Heroku are deliberately blocking DEV mode deployments. Everything works perfectly when tested locally with `symfony server:start`

Answer (score 7):

Heroku will not install dev dependencies in your dyno. This is documented here: [Build behaviour](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#build-behavior).

Specifically, heroku will run:

```
composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction
```

The theory goes that heroku is for production like code, so development dependencies do not belong there. Usually, these dependencies would only be installed on the developers' machines, not on any deployed application instance.

If you really need this on deployed code, I guess you should admit this are not development dependencies but regular dependencies, and move them from `require-dev` to `require`.

Comment: Thanks, I think we tried this earlier but should double check again on Wednesday when back in the office. Upvoted your answer already. Great suggestion :-)

Comment: Eventually this did not fix it, although it is the correct steps to fix it! Something else must be broken, I'll post when we find what has caused it. It has to be something different. Any ideas, let me know. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Adding APP_ENV=prod to my env vars solved this issue for me. Thanks a lot. However, now I'm getting an error that says
`remote:  !     Push failed: cannot parse Procfile.
remote:  !     Please try pushing again.`

Any ideas why this could be happening? My procfile has this line: `web: heroku-php-apache2 public/`

Answer (score 4):

Go into composer.json

Change this:

```
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
```

To this:

```
    "post-install-cmd": [
    ],
```

Then you don't run the post install scripts.

Answer (score 3):

As Sylvery said, Adding APP_ENV = prod in config vars fixed it for me.

```
heroku config:set APP_ENV=prod
```

or using heroku interface :

- Settings > Config Vars > button **Reveal Vars**
- Add "APP_ENV" in key and "prod" in value

Comment: This also solved the issue for us. Thanks for the heads-up 

Answer (score 0):

for me, solved by installing `symfony/twig-bundle` package, thanks to https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/30782#issuecomment-478911801

Answer (score 0):

I solve this setting APP_ENV=prod and running composer install -o ...

Answer (score -1):

I understand this will not be the ideal solution but since I have no idea how to make Heroku install the dependencies including dev, I made the fix by make the required packages installed on prod by move this package to `require` in `composer.json`

```
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/test-pack": "*"
```

Answer (score -6):

This solved the problem for me.
Run: `composer Install --dev`

Comment: This is not a good solution. The problem is the app environment is `dev` and the command run is `composer install --no-dev`. The app should be in `prod` (in .env file) as heroku is deploying the web site. Installing dev dependencies in prod is dangerous